# Whether $U\setminus C$ is open if $C$ is closed and $U$ is open

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

If $C$ is a closed set and $U$ is an open set, then is $U\setminus C$ open in an arbitrary metric space? I don't think this holds in the discrete metric space.

Comment: In discrete metric spaces, every set is open.

Comment: Yes, $U\setminus C = U \cap (X\setminus C)$ is open as the intersection of two open sets in the metric space $X$.

Answer (score 5):

If $C$ is closed, then its complement $C'$ is open, and $U-C=U\cap C'$ is open. This holds for any topological space.